# Want to Update OpenSSL with Ruby 2.0.0 Already Installed

Tags: terminal, macports, ruby, openssl, rvm

I have Ruby 2.0.0-p451 installed via RVM. From what I have read online the newer versions of openssl need Ruby 2 installed.  I'm running RVM 1.25.25.

I currently host Ruby on Rails websites on my Mac Mini Server running Mavericks and OS X Server 3.1.1.  I'm not currently using openssl but would like to upgrade it in light of the Heartbleed security vulnerability reported over a month ago.  I am not using SSL in any of my websites.  When I get ready to I may use openssl or Common Crypto.  I would like both of them to be current when I make my decision.

I have searched online and noticed there were problems with people that updated openssl without running Ruby 2.0.0.  I have not found any issues with updating openssl after Ruby 2 was installed.

I want to know the best way to upgrade openssl.  I do not use Homebrew or Macports.  However I believe that when I upgraded Ruby on Rails to 4.0.0 it installed/updated Macports on my server.

I have found the steps below on how to install it in the Terminal if you do not want to use RVM or Homebrew.  This [post](http://ameinikan.com/blog/2013/03/06/how-to-compile-and-install-ruby-2-dot-0-on-mac-without-homebrew-or-rvm/) was written in March 2013

```
cd Downloads/
cd openssl-1.0.1e/
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
make
sudo make install
```

Since I'm using RVM I need to know how to upgrade it and not mess up Ruby.  I'm open to use Macports but I need to know the command.  I would also like to know which version I should install (MD5, SHA, PGP sign, normal).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think Ruby on Rails installed Macports - this seems highly unlikely as RoR is pure ruby and uses Ruby Gems?

Comment: Ruby on Rails now checks to see what is needed in the background to help it work.  It will install what is missing on your system.  It's been a while since I upgraded from version 3 to 4 but I believe that happened.  Unfortunately I do not know how to check for it to see if it is in my system.